# Does NakedObjects.NET Integrate well with Editor Templates in MVC 2?

Tags: .net, templates, asp.net-mvc-2, naked-objects

I just recently listened to a [podcast](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=252) on [Naked Objects.NET](http://www.nakedobjects.net/home/index.shtml), and one thing came immediately to mind.

Does this framework support the use of Editor Templates?  Meaning, it would be really great if I could put in an editor template for, say a datetime or something, and have that effect the entire site.

Has anyone had any experience using MVC 2 Templates with NakedObjects.NET and do they integrate well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is answered here:

http://forum.nakedobjects.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3261

Comment: @rpawson Thanks that was actually me on the board asking the question, thought I'd try here as well!